# CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 100, so returning the closest version found: 99 with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, cdp

I created a bunch of scripts which worked fine in December 2021. I'm running them now and a few of them execute and pass but suddenly the execution stops and it shows the scripts are failed and skipped as follows:

```
test_Footer__BrokenImage is PASSED

Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 62727
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Apr 19, 2022 12:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Apr 19, 2022 12:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 100, so returning the closest version found: 99
Apr 19, 2022 12:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 100 of 99
test__BrokenImage is FAILED
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My chrome version is  100.0.4896.127
Chrome driver version is 100.0.4896.60

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 62727 
. 
Apr 19, 2022 12:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 100, so returning the closest version found: 99 
Apr 19, 2022 12:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 100 of 99
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

---

### Deep Dive

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You have downloaded and used *chromedriver=100.0* which got initiated successfully.
- But your are still using *chrome=99.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v99.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 99

Hence, instead of CDP implementation for version 100, CDP implementation for version 99 is found. So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=100.0* (as per [chromedriver=100.0.4896.60 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/notes.txt)).

[image: Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127]

Comment: But my chrome version is up to date
Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Possibly the setup with Selenium ponts to a different intance of Chrome installed at a custom location.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the current version of chrome and chrome driver. I used chrome and chromedriver version 95 and it runs well.